# Как обработать исключение IndexOutOfRangeException?

Tags: c#, .net, исключения, индексация

В задании указано создать 2 класса: в 1-ом создать и проинициализировать массив из 10 элементов типа int, конструктор по умолчанию и индексатор; во 2-ом классе - Main, в котором продемонстрировать ситуацию выхода за границы массива. Перехватить и обработать нужно исключение *в индексаторе*.
Помогите, как перехватить исключение ?

```
    class B
{
    private int[] a = new int[10] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    public int this[int i]
    {
        get { if (i >= 0 && i <= 10) return a[i]; else throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(); }
        set { if (i >= 0 && i <= 10) a[i] = value; else throw new IndexOutOfRangeException(); }
    }

}

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            B bi = new B();
            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            {Console.WriteLine(bi[i]);}
    }
}
```

Comment: По хорошему такие исключения не нужно обрабатывать, если возникает это исключение - значит в программе ошибка. Ну если только в качестве учебного примера...

Comment: имеется ошибка в коде...проверь код еще раз и ты поймешь

Answer (score 1):

```
get 
{
  try 
  {
    return a[i];
  }
  catch(IndexOutOfRangeException ex) 
  {
    // handle exception
    return 0;
  }
}
```